# Why did the batchOverflow hack in the "BEC" contract work?

Tags: overflow

I am currently learning about how the current batch overflow happens. But there are some points I don't understand.
The [article](https://medium.com/@peckshield/alert-new-batchoverflow-bug-in-multiple-erc20-smart-contracts-cve-2018-10299-511067db6536) says following:

> The vulnerable function is located in batchTransfer and the code is
>   shown in Figure 2. As indicated in line 257, the amount local variable
>   is calculated as the product of cnt and _value. The second parameter,
>   i.e., _value, can be an arbitrary 256 bits integer, say
>   0x8000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000(63
>   0’s). By having two _receivers passed into batchTransfer(), with that
>   extremely large _value, we can overflow amount and make it zero. With
>   amount zeroed, an attacker can then pass the sanity checks in lines
>   258–259 and make the subtraction in line 261 irrelevant. Finally, here
>   comes the interesting part: as shown in lines 262–265, the balance of
>   the two receivers would be added by the extremely large _value without
>   costing a dime in the the attacker’s pocket!

The image to the article:
[image]

So now, when the hacker enters the number, the number get's extremely huge. In the next step, the number even gets higher with multiplication with cnt which is the amount of receivers (let's say 2).

Why did the execution not stop in the line 259 as the amount the hacker transferred was way higher than his balance?

**Can someone please explain to me what exactly happened here?**

Comment: If you agree that `uint256 amount` could overflow and become equal to `0`, then you could also see how `require(_value > 0 && balances[msg.sender] >= amount);` would always return true, thus the rest of the code would run unchecked.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that's true. My fault was, that I did not read it correctly. I understand it now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why did the execution not stop in
>   the line 259 as the amount the hacker transferred was way higher than
>   his balance?

If the contract is called with the arguments

```
batchTransfer([addressA,addressB],0x8000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000)
```

line 257 becomes

```
uint256 amount = 2 * 0x8000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000
```

which is 0x0 due to overflow.

So `amount` in the subsequent evaluation is 0. So the check in line 259 becomes:

```
require(0x8000,0... > 0 && balance[msg.sender] >= 0);
```

The argument to `require` evaluates to true so the contract execution will continue. And in the for-loop the huge amounts of `0x800....` will be transferred to `addressA` and `addressB` and 0 (the amount which was the result of an overflowed calculation) will be subtracted from the originator's balance.

The total amount of tokens has just increased by 2^256 tokens.

Talk about hyperinflation!

Comment: LOL. I just got it. I actually did not correctly read the whole thing. There is "amount" and "_value", while amount is the whole thing, the total value, that gets to zero because of overflow and _value is what each user gets which remains as the huge value. Thank you for this!

Comment: Brain farts is an unavoidable part of programming. That should also be clear from the code that this question is about :)

Comment: Yes it is, the code shows clearly what happened. I did not fully read the whole code ;-).

Comment: Neither did the developers of that contract :)

Comment: It's bad that I laughed at this.